# Check if jPlayer is stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

How can i determine if jPlayer has stop?
I wanted to throw an event or alert when ever jPlayer has stop.

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    stop: function () {
        alert('Player has stop');
    }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the pause event. If you read the documentation, it says all events. http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-events

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    pause: function () {
        alert('Player has stop');
    }
});
```